# Failed to easy_install/pip install python package rpy2 on windows

Tags: python, installation, pip, rpy2

I'm trying to install the python package rpy2 but failed to do so. I need help to be able to install the rpy2 package.
Im trying to install it on a windows system. I have R version 3.0.2 and python 2.7
Below is the error message I got when trying to pip install:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts\pip-script.py run on 01/03/14 10:58:22
Downloading/unpacking rpy2
Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/
URLs to search for versions for rpy2:
* https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/
Analyzing links from page https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/r/rpy2/rpy2-2.0.8.win32-py2.6.msi#md5=2c8d174862c0d132db0c65777412fe04 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/); unknown archive format: .msi
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/rpy2/rpy2-2.0.8.tar.gz#md5=c63a56aca8a352719ee3c91805beee66 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.0.8
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/rpy2/rpy2-2.1.0.tar.gz#md5=90737bf49d9d340937921fbc85dbf364 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.1.0
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/rpy2/rpy2-2.1.1.tar.gz#md5=da5f58597a7ced6d9480c6fe563a2a40 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.1.1
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/rpy2/rpy2-2.1.2.tar.gz#md5=b0d74cedcf05f777bf91f0f08aad015a (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.1.2
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/rpy2/rpy2-2.1.3.tar.gz#md5=51544f516942b99f4825dbe776049b1c (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.1.3
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/rpy2/rpy2-2.1.4.tar.gz#md5=cf4e0d80ba498a6d76f107531966478d (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.1.4
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/rpy2/rpy2-2.1.5.tar.gz#md5=957928621002593ca9b85b94ce8c790a (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.1.5
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/rpy2/rpy2-2.1.6.tar.gz#md5=d2cb7db347057c4a9d128139b686f976 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.1.6
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/rpy2/rpy2-2.1.7.tar.gz#md5=e8e8db05f13644ce04784888156af471 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.1.7
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/rpy2/rpy2-2.1.8.tar.gz#md5=378c053f5eac7e96c500c8ebcac00a42 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.1.8
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/rpy2/rpy2-2.1.9.tar.gz#md5=afe629914e7263900e5d15d419f69865 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.1.9
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/rpy2/rpy2-2.2.0.tar.gz#md5=a42a7f1e6ddb10dc3a1886c2f4309fab (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.2.0
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/rpy2/rpy2-2.2.1.tar.gz#md5=422a31a1b3cf36efafdae53306f7f422 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.2.1
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/rpy2/rpy2-2.2.2.tar.gz#md5=7690d8fa747e62cd27cfacfa45f4a07b (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.2.2
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/rpy2/rpy2-2.2.3.tar.gz#md5=70d2181168b3ba9168bab48654f4028d (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.2.3
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/rpy2/rpy2-2.2.4.tar.gz#md5=0192a3c05d8d97971e2bcf888944aff5 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.2.4
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/rpy2/rpy2-2.2.5.tar.gz#md5=aa9c0c3120716705b28127323cc4ac6d (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.2.5
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/rpy2/rpy2-2.2.6.tar.gz#md5=32d73a3e4acb915ce15d958c9092dcb8 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.2.6
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/rpy2/rpy2-2.2.7.tar.gz#md5=6b8e32b66fcb60490022e3bc840b96ec (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.2.7
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/rpy2/rpy2-2.3.0.tar.gz#md5=ad140fc1a1280cf394e4d8dedbcfaaba (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.3.0
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/rpy2/rpy2-2.3.0alpha1.tar.gz#md5=1fe4d18abe4140900ed812d091bbd913 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.3.0alpha1
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/rpy2/rpy2-2.3.0beta1.tar.gz#md5=9f75b07ccb916911ab810ec40f6870b0 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.3.0beta1
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/rpy2/rpy2-2.3.1.tar.gz#md5=8d68dbd8947931975304dc633bbb843c (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.3.1
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/rpy2/rpy2-2.3.2.tar.gz#md5=b811810ece66adde25f9ed0ecb2733e5 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.3.2
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/rpy2/rpy2-2.3.3.tar.gz#md5=6cd95eb70645577cb53198ef0a32395e (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.3.3
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/rpy2/rpy2-2.3.4.tar.gz#md5=38fa0fb1b2543e65655ced3d6741ba68 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.3.4
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/rpy2/rpy2-2.3.5.tar.gz#md5=56341b6f425149b60765b19641e953a4 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.3.5
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/rpy2/rpy2-2.3.6.tar.gz#md5=d64aed40e7b92581eb859890b291e88c (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.3.6
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/rpy2/rpy2-2.3.7.tar.gz#md5=e71efa65b66ede146a766ae7d753a7f6 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.3.7
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/rpy2/rpy2-2.3.8.tar.gz#md5=f331120aeeb1b27118d4e3360f2ec45d (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version: 2.3.8
Ignoring link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/rpy2/rpy2-2.3.0alpha1.tar.gz#md5=1fe4d18abe4140900ed812d091bbd913 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version 2.3.0alpha1 is a pre-release (use --pre to allow).
Ignoring link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/rpy2/rpy2-2.3.0beta1.tar.gz#md5=9f75b07ccb916911ab810ec40f6870b0 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/), version 2.3.0beta1 is a pre-release (use --pre to allow).
Using version 2.3.8 (newest of versions: 2.3.8, 2.3.7, 2.3.6, 2.3.5, 2.3.4, 2.3.3, 2.3.2, 2.3.1, 2.3.0, 2.2.7, 2.2.6, 2.2.5, 2.2.4, 2.2.3, 2.2.2, 2.2.1, 2.2.0, 2.1.9, 2.1.8, 2.1.7, 2.1.6, 2.1.5, 2.1.4, 2.1.3, 2.1.2, 2.1.1, 2.1.0, 2.0.8)
Downloading from URL https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/rpy2/rpy2-2.3.8.tar.gz#md5=f331120aeeb1b27118d4e3360f2ec45d (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/)
Running setup.py egg_info for package rpy2

running egg_info
creating pip-egg-info\rpy2.egg-info
writing pip-egg-info\rpy2.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to pip-egg-info\rpy2.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info\rpy2.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info\rpy2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found


Error: Tried to guess R's HOME but no R command in the PATH.

Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

running egg_info

creating pip-egg-info\rpy2.egg-info

writing pip-egg-info\rpy2.egg-info\PKG-INFO

writing top-level names to pip-egg-info\rpy2.egg-info\top_level.txt

writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info\rpy2.egg-info\dependency_links.txt

writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info\rpy2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'

warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found



Error: Tried to guess R's HOME but no R command in the PATH.
```

Comment: Well, it says it didn't find R in Path. Do you have R in your path?

Comment: I'm new to this so could you give me an example to how that would look?

Comment: Can you execute the `R` interpreter from your command line without using it's full path? If not, then it isn't on your `PATH` and you should add it and try again (you can use your google-fu if you don't know how to do that).

Comment: I'm sorry , I do not understand what you mean by running from command line, could you give me an example?

Comment: Use precompiled binaries. http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-dev/html/overview.html#download